# Как получить результат SQL-запроса

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с SQLite. Мне при добавлении записи в БД нужно проверить существует ли такая запись. Делаю я это так:

```
String dbIf = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.dbName + " WHERE " + DBHelper.barcodeIt + " = " + barcodeItem.getText().toString() + " LIMIT 1)";
sqlDB.execSQL(dbIf);
```

Вопрос: как мне вытащить в java резльтат?

Comment: в SQLlite android есть [метод update()](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/75-urok-35-metody-query-i-delete-s-ukazaniem-uslovija.html), который либо обновляет запись, если она уже существует, либо добавляет новую, если записи с таким ID еще не существует, если это то, что вам нужно получить в итоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширение ответа сверху - т.е. пример кода:

```
public static boolean checkIssetNewsLinkInDB(Context context, String link){
    // check link to issue news in DB
    String selection = DatabaseDescription.News.COLUMN_LINK_NEWS + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{link};

    F1NewsReaderDatabaseHelper helper = new F1NewsReaderDatabaseHelper(context);
    Cursor cursor = helper.getWritableDatabase().query(DatabaseDescription.News.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.close();
        helper.close();
        return false;
    }

    cursor.close();
    helper.close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У dbHelpera есть метод query() и rawQuery() для чисто sql строки, которые возвращают объект cursor, в котором и лежит результат, но перед этим нужно вызвать openReadableDataBase()

Comment: А можете скинуть пример?

Comment: У меня компа под рукой сейчас нет, можно загуглить.